# Cardinal of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\newcommand{\card}{\operatorname{card}}$

It's an easy question, but I don't know how to start. I need to prove that:

1) If $X$ is finite and $Y\subset X$, then $\card(Y) \leq \card (X)$

2) If $X$ and $Y$ are finites, then $X\cup Y$ is finite and $$\card(X\cup Y) = \card(X)+\card(Y)-\card(X\cap Y)$$

Comment: Start by writing down the definitions.

Comment: 2 is known as the "Inclusion-Exclusion Principle" so it is fairly easy to look up if you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: I don't see why you need $X$ finite for your first proposition.

Comment: If X isn't finite, computing its cardinality becomes a bit tricky as the Natural Numbers and the Real Numbers both have infinite cardinality but this has to be expressed in non-trivial ways I'm thinking.

Comment: What definition of cardinality are you using?

Comment: @JBKing yeah! thanks.

Comment: @CameronBuie is the number of elements of the set. But today I learned another definition using an inyective function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\card}{\operatorname{card}}$

What does it mean to say that $\card(A)\le\card(B)$?  It means there is a one-to-one function from $A$ into $B$.  So if $X\subseteq Y$, then just consider the identity function on $X$.  Its domain is $X$ and it takes values in $Y$.  And it's one-to-one.

Your second statement is equivalent to
$$
\card(X\cup Y)+\card(X\cap Y) = \card(X)+\card(Y).
$$
So what is the sum of two cardinalities?  The sum $\card(X)+\card(Y)$ is the cardinality of a set $A\cup B$ where $\card(A)=\card(X)$ and $\card(B)=\card(Y)$ and $A\cap B=\varnothing$.  So you could take $A$ to be the set $\{(x,1) : x\in X\}$ and $B$ to be the set $\{(y,0) : y\in Y\}$.  Then $A\cap B=\varnothing$, since the second components in the pairs fail to agree.  Then you need to show there's a function from $X$ to $A$ that's one-to-one and onto, and similarly there's a function from $Y$ to $B$ that's one-to-one and onto.  Then $\card(A\cup B)$ is the sum.  Then work on the left side in the same way: say $C=\{ (u,2) : u\in X\cup Y \}$ and $D=\{(v,3) : v\in X\cap Y\}$.  Then $\card(C\cup D)$ is the sum on the left.  Then finally, you need to show there's a function from $C\cup D$ to $A\cup B$ that's one-to-one and onto.  So ask yourself: which element of $C\cup D$ should correspond to which element of $A\cup B$?

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Yes! it was enough, thanks you so much!